# Resolution change affects dialog

Tags: android, dialog

In my app I have some pop up dialog.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(Dialog.WIDTH,Dialog.HEIGHT);
dialog.show();
```

And in my Dialog class I have

```
public static final int WIDTH = 1000;
public static final int HEIGHT = 700;
```

So It works fine on my tablet (ASUS Transformer Pad TF300T)
But now I have another tablet (ASUS ME302C) and my dialog sizes are small!
But they both have the same screen size.

Comment: Screen size may be the same, but do they have the same resolution? If you have Dialog with size 500x500 px it will appear smaller on device with resolution 1024x768 than on device with resolution 800x600.

Comment: Yeah the resolution is different. So How can I write my code to avoid that kind of situations for my dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dp instead of px...
If you can't, beacuse you're doing it by code, you have to find the device density and scale by that multiplication factor.
ldpi displays have a factor of 0.75
mdpi (default) displays have a factor of 1.0
hdpi displays have a factor of 1.5
xhdpi displays have a factor of 2.0
xxhdpi displays have a factor of 3.0
xxxhdpi displays have a factor of 4.0

Here's a method that does it for you:

```
private final float getDensityScale()
{
    final DisplayMetrics metrics =
        Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.density;
}
```

Multiply your values by that scale factor and you're done.